# MySQL query most recent revision in a query with several joins

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. I need to amend the query to pull the most recent revisions to the data, using the `r.timestamp` value.

```
select 
c.id as catID, 
c.name as catName, 
ec.description, 
t.approved, 
r.name,
r.timestamp, 
u.username
from cats c
join things t on c.id = t.id
left join east_cats ec on t.id = ec.cat_id
left join review r on e.id = r.id and r.type = 'description'
left join users u on u.id = r.timestamp
group by c.id
```

This query gives me the result

```
catID  catName  ...  r.name  r.timestamp
2  Ellen  ...  Editor1  2021-03-03
3  James  ...  Editor2  2021-04-05
4  Sarah  ...  Editor3  2020-04-06
```

Here, the query is pulling the earliest timestamp, not the most recent one.

You can see what I mean when I remove the group by aggregate function:

```
catID  catName ...  r.name  r.timestamp
2  Ellen  ...  Editor1  2021-03-03
2  Ellen  ...  Editor5  2021-05-05
3  James  ...  Editor2  2021-04-05
3  James  ...  Editor6  2021-04-06
4  Sarah  ...  Editor3  2020-04-06
```

What I want:

```
catID  catName  ...  r.name  r.timestamp
2  Ellen  ...  Editor5  2021-05-05
3  James ...  Editor6  2021-04-06
4 Sarah ...  Editor3  2020-04-06
```

I thought I could do this by adding `having max(r.timestamp)` under `group by c.id`, but the query is still returning the grouped c.id with the earlier timestamp, not the most recent one. What am I doing wrong? Do I need an inner join here, and if so, where would I work it into the query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need a row_number for that, but please make a [mre]

Comment: Added more info; thanks.

Comment: mysql 8 by any chance?

Comment: Yes! MySQL 8.0.21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
  c.id AS catID,  c.name AS catName,  ec.description,  t.approved,
  r.name,  r.timestamp,  u.username,
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY r.timestamp DESC) AS Rownum
FROM
  cats c
  JOIN things t ON c.id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN east_cats ec ON t.id = ec.cat_id
  LEFT JOIN review r ON e.id = r.id AND r.type = 'description' 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = r.timestamp) AS subquery1
WHERE Rownum=1;
```

I've added [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function with a partition on `c.name` then order by `r.timestamp` in descending so that the last/latest date will get the number `1`. Then I thought that the result of `ROW_NUMBER()` can be used in `HAVING` **without doing any testing** but it actually can't be used that way. Thanks to OP's own finding and suggestion, I modified my answer to make the query as a subquery then add filter `WHERE RowNum=1`.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like it should work but Workbench is giving me a syntax error. 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY r.timestamp DESC) AS Rownum from cats c j'

Comment: oops my mistake @Peter .. that should be `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `()`.. please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a new error now -'You cannot use the alias 'Rownum' of an expression containing a window function in this context.' Rownum works great and i can easily filter out the non-1s in the CSV report, but I can't figure out how to get this right. Should I use a subquery perhaps?

Comment: I see, looks like using `RowNum` in `HAVING` is not allowed. My apology, I usually test the query on a fiddle or something to confirm that it's workable but it seems like this time I'm over confident that the query I've suggested will work. Yes, subquery will definitely work (this time I've tested it).